# Word 2007 mail merge with just the packaging API

Tags: ms-word, docx, mailmerge

For a project we need to build some sort of mail merging with Word documents. I prefer this without Word automation. I recall that there is a way to create a .docx file (sort of template) for your letters that you can then just load with the packaging API and add a data file to (e.g. XML). The person who then opens that file will see the letter merged with that data.

Does anyone know if that method actually exist and how to do it?

Comment: There are two distinct approaches: traditional mail merge, which uses field codes, and content control data binding. Do you care which you use? (This may come down to who is authoring the templates). When a person opens the merged output, will this be with Microsoft Word?

Comment: Maybe the users will be working with Word 2003 and office compatibility pack to edit docx files. Will they be able to work with the second approach in that case? I don't prefer approaches that require word automation on the server anyway...

Comment: The content control data binding approach isn't fully compatible with Word 2003; not sure whether Word 2003 will perform the binding or not.  So assuming you want to merge data into mail merge fields, what is your preferred language for doing this in?

Answer (score 1):

No. Even Office Open XML SDK doesn't provide that.

You will need to roll out you own or use some existing library. For example: [Templater](http://templater.info/). Disclamer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Fill_Mergefields.aspx

It uses the Open XML SDK to find MERGEFIELDs in Microsoft Word documents and replace them with the provided data.

It also has some conventions which if followed provide additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

[JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) can work with DOC format files providing mail merge capabilities - the end result is a document with your data merged.  You need to install OpenOffice or LibreOffice.  The conversions are reasonable and you have options beyond DOC format for output.  They don't use automation and can run on several platforms.